# Can anyone help me with drag and drop functionality of files using javascript supported by all versions of IE?

Tags: javascript, file, drag-and-drop

I have text box. When I drag and drop a file into it, the path, or content of the file should be displayed. The major concern being it's compatibility with all versions of IE. I am a beginner in JavaScript programming. Can anyone suggest any idea or some tricks to get through?

Comment: Even with IE 1.0??? I don't think it is possible...

Answer (score 0):

By far the best solution is to use one of the Javascript libraries. I know script.aculo.us, but I'm sure that others such as jquery, dojo and mootools would do just as well. 
All these libraries, as well as making Javscript programming much easier, have hacks in to cope with non-standard browsers (ie IE), so that you - the programmer - don't have to worry about which browser.